# Does Parallels Desktop support hardware virtualization for the client VM?

Tags: macos, virtualization, parallels-desktop, windows

I have a new MacBook pro (I just switched from PC), and an older scanner (a Mustek A3 USB).

The scanner comes with drivers for OS 9 (I assume that's a non-starter on OS X), and Windows XP.

I have Parallels Desktop 6 running a Windows 7 installation on my MacBook.

Windows 7 comes with "Windows XP mode", a Virtual Machine running XP. This is what I used to run my scanner previously, on my PC.

However, Windows XP mode refuses to start inside the Parallels-powered Windows 7, complaining that the host machine (ie. Windows 7) doesn't have hardware-supported Virtualization. Whichis Parallels Desktop's "fault" as it's providing the virtual, simulated hardware.

Is there any way I can get Windows XP running on Windows 7 inside Parallels Desktop? Is there some setting I can change?

I guess simply creating a second Parallels VM running XP directly would be a workaround, but I don't have a separate copy of XP handy, and would like to avoid having to buy one.

Comment: Honestly, a new scanner will cost you less than an XP license and it'll work from OS X and Win7. I'd buy a new scanner.

Comment: @Ian not in this case - it's an A3 one, and a pretty decent one, too... An XP license costs about $30-$40 on eBay, if all else fails that'll be the way I'll be taking.

Comment: Ah. Yea, that's a pretty big scan surface. I can see why you'd want to keep it going. I think  you're destined to buy a copy of XP. Though I'd be wary of buying software licenses off eBay.

Comment: @Ian yeah, I agree. I've been burned before so I buy from members in good standing only that are also registered companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, Parallels does not support Windows XP Mode in Windows 7 directly.

[Parallels Knowledge-base article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/113303)

**However,** the VMware knowledge-base does list a pair of patches from Microsoft ([x86 patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3248) and [x64 patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6906)) that remove the requirement for the hardware virtualisation on XP mode which should allow Parallels to also run the XP mode.

[VMware Knowledge-base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017526)